# NoClassDefFoundError after uploading jars to Hazelcast Cloud via Client User Code Deployment

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-cloud

I'm currently trying Hazelcast Cloud and I need to upload jar dependencies to the Hazelcast Cloud servers. I have about 20mb to upload, uploading seems fine via the Client User Code Deployment feature, however once upload finishes and try to use the classes I get this error. I'm using both Jet streams and IMDG maps, sets, lists and executor service. Are some features that are not supported on Hazelcast Cloud or am I missing something? I was thinking maybe I also need to `addClass` as opposed to just `addJar` when using the Client User Code Deployment feature programmatically.

Here is the code to add the dependency.

```java
ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig = 
    new ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig();

clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addJar("path to jar containing com.my.jarlibrary.SomeClass");

clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.setEnabled(true);

ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig(); // Jet & Hazelcast config
config.setUserCodeDeploymentConfig(clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig);

// I also tried added the class after adding the jar which contains it, 
// and same error comes up.
clientUserCodeDeploymentConfig.addClass(SomeClass.class);
```

Here is the error I get:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.client.UndefinedErrorCodeException: 
Class name: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, Message:  com/my/jarlibrary/SomeClass
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:109)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:33)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:163)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientUserCodeDeploymentService.deploy(ClientUserCodeDeploymentService.java:172)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.clientside.HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.onClusterConnect(HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.java:444)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnectorServiceImpl.connectAsOwner(ClusterConnectorServiceImpl.java:150)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnectorServiceImpl.connectToCandidate(ClusterConnectorServiceImpl.java:252)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnectorServiceImpl.connectToClusterInternal(ClusterConnectorServiceImpl.java:192)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnectorServiceImpl.access$000(ClusterConnectorServiceImpl.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnectorServiceImpl$1.call(ClusterConnectorServiceImpl.java:279)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClusterConnectorServiceImpl$1.call(ClusterConnectorServiceImpl.java:275)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.client.UndefinedErrorCodeException: Class name: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, Message: com/my/jarlibrary/SomeClass
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassSource.define(ClassSource.java:50)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.ClassLocator.defineClassFromClient(ClassLocator.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.UserCodeDeploymentService.defineClass(UserCodeDeploymentService.java:72)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.usercodedeployment.impl.operation.DeployClassesOperation.run(DeployClassesOperation.java:50)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:170)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:210)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:199)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:407)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:434)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:648)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:633)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:592)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:256)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:61)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMultiTargetMessageTask.processMessage(AbstractMultiTargetMessageTask.java:57)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:129)
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
    at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:96)
    ... 16 more)
```

Comment: I made a mistake when writting the question text, please replace this class with com/my/jarlibrary/SomeClass, then yes it was added before.

Answer (score 2):

If you load `SomeClass` from another classloader, Hazelcast client won't be able to load its class definition, thus throw this exception. 
An example scenario would be like the following: You have Spring boot app running on Tomcat. 
SomeClass is loaded by Tomcat classloader while Hazelcast client classes are loaded via spring boot classloader. 
In this case, Hazelcast client has access to SomeClass but not to its class definition which is loaded via the classloader.

As a workaround, you need to tell Hazelcast client which classloader to use:

```
clientConfig.setClassLoader(SomeClass.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: It should work by just adding the jar? Why do we need to add the class too?

Comment: It should work by adding the jars, make sure you include all dependencies. If you want to redeploy the classes/jars, make sure you restart the cluster first.

Comment: It doesn't work with this class loader work around or with just the jars, what should I try next? Is there a way to look at the hazelcast server instances on the cloud?

Comment: Classloader workaround is only when you load the individual class, not for JAR loading. Note that it is enough to load only the JAR. As the next step, 1) could you please restart the Hazelcast cloud cluster? 2) Then, just `addJar`, and see if you get the exception.  3) Share the cluster ID at the end of the URL so we will check the exception logs